# Xamarin C# - INotifyPropertyChanged Model - Error in JSON Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a c# User model which is synced with the Azure Mobile services.
The definition of the User class is as follows:

```
public class Users : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    private string id;
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); }
    }



    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    private string name;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    [JsonProperty("Email")]
    private string email;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; OnPropertyChanged("Email"); }
    }

    [JsonProperty("Password")]
    private string password;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { password = value; OnPropertyChanged("Password"); }
    }  
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(propertyName != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Now, in the XAML page code, once the user logs in, I try to get the user, like so:

```
var user = (await App.MobileService.GetTable<Users>().Where(u => u.Email == this.txtEmail.Text).ToListAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
```

If I remove the JsonProperty() and JsonIgnore() on private and public members, I get the error: NewtonSoft.Json Deserialization error.

In the above code, is there any simpler way other than declaring JsonProperty() and JsonIgnore on each private and public fields respectively?

Comment: Stab in the dark but I would of expected that you need to have your JSON attributes the other way around i.e. Properties on the public properties and ignores on the private fields.

Comment: Apologies, that doesn't answer your question. I think that if your JSON properties match your model properties then the deserialization can happen implicitly, without the attributes?

Comment: What if you split out this class into `UserEntity` for EF and `UserJsonEntity` instead of  one class? Perhaps using automapper to convert to and from classes https://automapper.org/ .

Comment: It probably throws an exception, because the `PropertyChanged` event is null. Check that first.